# How would a pitbull do as part of a livestock guardian team?

Tags: dogs

How effective would a pitbull be as part of a livestock guardian team? Not necessarily the only dog, maybe one dog alerting and the others jumping in.

Comment: Not a good idea. Stick to the breeds that specialise as livestock guardians. I'll try and write an answer soon